# Start a function which controls available new version on store to push a notification while even app is not active

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, app-store

I have an application for `web and ios devices`. I control that both versions are same or not. The version information is stored on server.

What I want to do is:

App will check version of app(the appstore version) with web version through `wcf` method. If they are not equal then the app will not continue to call other views after login page until the new version is installed. But to install the new version I need to check the app store also for the new available version.

There is a possibility that the user will not open the app again. So if it is available then a notification will appear to download it even if app is not active.

So after checking versions and if they are not equal, an app store checking function has to start to check the new app version on appstore.If there is an available one, that function push a notification for the new version on appstore. And this function has to continue to work when app is not active.

Is it possible to do and if it is how can I start a control to push a notification for a new app version while even app is not active? or if it is not possible is there another way? Thank you so much.

I researched on web but I started to get confused a lot. So I asked here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like backend stuff to me. Upon login just check the current version on appstore like this http://itunes.apple.com/search?entity=software&country=US&term=yourappnamehere this will give you a JSON object. After comparison you can easy send push notification to that user and let them know that newer version is available on appstore. All you need to do in XCode is ask for push-notifications permission and then send device UDID to your backend, so you can push notification if app versions differ.

Comment: I found how to check new app version with iVersion. I ask for how can I check this always even without user open the application.I looked this http://www.raywenderlich.com/32963/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-2 and it looks scary :/ Should I write a server?

Comment: Yes you should if you want to send push notifications to your users. There is no other way arround. Not only this and you should have a webservice to implement all this app version comparisons as well as storing users app version on server. When app version changes on appstore run a script to notify all users via push notifications service.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the information. I will try this with starting that tutorial